# Add NativeScript to Angular project

Tags: android, ios, angular, nativescript

I am trying to create a mobile app using and existing web application I have previously developed.

For that I am using NativeScript because it can be used with an existing Angular project using a code-sharing structure.

Following the docs in their website:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project

I convert the web project to a code-sharing structure :

```
ng add @nativescript/schematics
```

But I am getting a error in the console:

```
trustedSubscriber._addParentTeardownLogic is not a function
```

And then when I go to run it in the mobiles:

```
tns run android --bundle
```

or

```
tns run ios --bundle
```

I am getting an error (Seems that is not detecting it as a NativeScript project):

```
No project found at or above '/Path/to/my/project' and neither was a --path specified.
```

Comment: After running `ng add @nativescript/schematics`, did you notice the changes on your project structure, do you find the new files specific to NativeScript that makes sure the migration was successful.

Comment: No, there is the problem. ng add@nativescript/schematics is not working propertly. (I have edited the question)

Comment: Whats your Angular version?

Comment: Is Angular: 6.1.6

Comment: Did you find a solution ?